# SELECT+UPDATE to avoid returning the same result

Tags: php, mysql, cron, queue, debian

I have a cron task running every *x* seconds on *n* servers. It will "SELECT FROM table WHERE time_scheduled<CURRENT_TIME" and then perform a lengthy task on this result set.

My problem is now: How do I avoid having two seperate servers perform the same task at the same time?

The idea is to update *time_scheduled* with a set interval after selecting it. But if two servers happen to run the query at the same time, that will be too late, no?

All ideas are welcome. It doesnt have to be a strict MySQL solution.

Thanks!

Comment: mysql server is shared between all the servers?

Comment: Yes, they all pull from the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you have a single MySQL instance, and connections from your *n* servers to run this processing job.  You're implementing a job queue here.

The `table` you mention needs to use the InnoDB access method (or one of the other transaction-friendly access methods offered by Percona or MariaDB).

Do these items in your table need to be processed in batches? That is, are they somehow inter-related? Or is it possible for your server processes to handle them one-by-one? This is an important question, because you'll get better load balancing between your server processes if you can handle them individually or in small batches.  Let's assume the small batches.

The idea is to prevent any server process from grabbing onto a row in your table if some other server process has that row.   I've had to do this kind of thing a lot, and here is my suggestion; I know this works.

First, add an integer column to your table. Call it "working" or some such thing. Give it a default value of zero.

Second, assign a permanent id number to each server. The last part of the server's IP address (for example, if the server's IP address is 10.1.0.123, the id number is 123) is a good choice, because it's probably unique in your environment.

Then, when a server's grabbing work to do, use these two SQL queries.

```
  UPDATE table
     SET working = :this_server_id
   WHERE working = 0
     AND time_scheduled < CURRENT_TIME
   ORDER BY time_scheduled
   LIMIT 1

  SELECT table_id, whatever, whatever
    FROM table
   WHERE working = :this_server_id
```

The first query will consistently grab a batch of rows to work on. If another server process comes in at the same time, it won't ever grab the same rows, because no process can grab rows unless `working = 0`.   Notice that the LIMIT 1 will limit your batch size. You don't have to do this, but you can. I also threw in `ORDER BY` to process the rows first that have been waiting the longest. That's probably a useful way to do things.

The second query retrieves the information you need to do the work. Don't forget to retrieve the primary key values (I called them `table_id`) for the rows you're working on.

Then, your server process does whatever it needs to do.

When it's done, it needs to throw the row back into the queue for a later time.  To do that, the server process needs to set the `time_scheduled` to whatever it needs to be, then to set `working = 0`.  So, for example, you could run this query for each row you're processing.

```
  UPDATE table 
     SET time_scheduled = CURRENT_TIME + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE,
         working = 0
   WHERE table_id = ?table_id_from_previous_query
```

That's it.

Except for one thing.  In the real world these queuing systems get fouled up sometimes. Server processes crash. Etc. Etc. See Murphy's Law. You need a monitoring query. That's easy in this system.

This query will give a list of all jobs that are more than five minutes overdue, along with the server that's supposed to be working on them.

```
 SELECT working, COUNT(*) stale_jobs
   FROM table
  WHERE time_scheduled < CURRENT_TIME - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
  GROUP BY WORKING
```

If this query comes up empty, all is well. If it comes up with lots of jobs with `working` set to zero, your servers aren't keeping up.  If it comes up with jobs with `working` set to some server's id number, that server is taking a lunch break.

You can reset all the jobs assigned to the server that's gone to lunch with this query, if need be.

```
  UPDATE table
     SET working=0
   WHERE working=?server_id_at_lunch
```

By the way, a compound index on `(working, time_scheduled)` will probably help this perform well.

Comment: I think that could work well. Ill try to implement it and see if I run into any unforeseen problems. Thank you!